# rotate hexagon button but not the image

Tags: wpf

I have button and shape(hexagon)in it which I want to rotate. But I don't want it's background to be rotated. 
How to place an image to rotated hexagon button?
here is my code:

```
<Button Height="182" Width="155" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1.368">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="mob.png"/>
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="187.488" Y="-187.488"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Button.RenderTransform>

    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
              <ed:RegularPolygon Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
 </Button>
```

Comment: Sorry it's a little hard to get what you're after there, you want the polygon to have the render transform not the whole button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I suggest you create a ControlTemplate to take care of everything you're after here?

In the template ensure you draw your polygon and then rotate it to whatever value you require then add a ContentPresenter control into your template. This should draw whatever the contents of your button is. In your cas eI would make the mod.png the content.

Binding a ContentPrester requires the use of TemplateBinding as follows.

```
<!-- DRAW HEXAGON HERE -->
<ContentPresenter Conent="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
```

and ensure you apply any rotation to the hexagon and not the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a `RenderTransform` on the Button, as that would rotate the whole filled polygon. Instead of the `ed:RegularPolygon` you may use a `Path` with a geometry that contains the polyline, e.g. a `PathGeometry`:

```
<Button Height="182" Width="155">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="mob.png"/>
    </Button.Background>

    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathGeometry.Transform>
                            ... put transform here ...
                        </PathGeometry.Transform>
                        <PathGeometry.Figures>
                            ... put polyline data here ...
                        </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```